# Ajax and jQuery with PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code which posts data using jQuery and ajax to itself.

```
<input type="button" id="butt"  value="button11111111111111" >
<script>
$("#butt").on('click',function(e)
    {
        $.ajax(
            {
                type:'POST',
                url:'test.php',
                data:product_type:"cake"
            });
    });
</script>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['product_type']))
         $abc=$_POST['product_type'];

 if(isset($abc))
      echo $abc; 
  ?>
```

Now when I try to run this code.I do get the ok status inside the **Network Console** of Chrome but this code doesn't echo the output.

I simply want to display the result that has been passed by the ajax method.

I am new to ajax and jquery so i don't know much about how they work exactly but is it possible? 
If yes, then how could i achieve that without actually refreshing the page?

Comment: No, in this way you can't. I think that the problem isn't that you're new to ajax but you have to understand how this page is executed again. Untill you refresh your page the php code is never executed. So i think that the easiest solution for your problem is to output the result using jquery.

Comment: how do i do that ? Could you show me the code?yeah i thought as well .Php code runs only when you refresh the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I think you want, i.e. test.php is the source page **AND** the ajax page!

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['product_type'])) {
        Header("Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");
        $abc=$_POST['product_type'];
        if(isset($abc)) {
            echo $abc;
        }
    }
    else {
?>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">   </script>
<input type="button" id="butt"  value="button11111111111111" >
<script>
    $("#butt").on('click',function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'test.php',
            data: {
                product_type:"cake"
            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert('got ' + data);
            }
        });

    });
</script>
</html>
<?php
    }
?>
```